# Geometric mean of positive measures

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory

Let me given with an obvious example. Let $\Omega\subset{\mathbb R}^n$ be an open domain. If $f,g\in L^1(\Omega)$ and $f,g\ge0$, then $\sqrt{fg}\,\in L^1(\Omega)$.

Now let me replace the absolutely continuous measures $f(x)dx$ and $g(x)dx$, by a pair $\lambda,\mu$ of non-negative bounded measures on $\Omega$.

> Is there a natural way to define a geometric mean $\sqrt{\lambda\mu}$ as a non-negative measure ?

Here is an incomplete attempt: remark that if $a,b\in[0,\infty)$, then $\sqrt{ab}=\inf_{p,q>0}\frac{ap+bq}{2\sqrt{pq}}\,$. This suggests to define
$$\langle\sqrt{\lambda\mu},\phi\rangle:=\inf_h\{\langle\lambda,h\phi\rangle+\langle\mu,\frac\phi{h}\rangle\}\qquad\forall\phi\in C^+_K(\Omega)$$
where the infimum runs over function $h\in C(\overline{\Omega})$ that are strictly positive. This definition has several nice features: - it yields the correct function when applied to $L^1$-functions, - as a function of $\phi$, it is positive and homogeneous of degree one. However, it is not clear whether this defines a linear form.

Answer (score 4):

Any two measures are a.c. with respect to their sum, and you may take the geometric mean of the densities. This is the same definition as yours with infimum.

Answer (score 1):

This is what is called "Hellinger integral" and appears in the definition of the [Hellinger distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hellinger_distance).